# can a page table be viewed on a linux machine

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Recently i have read that page table is a per process entity, i was thinking is it possible to view page table for a particular process on a Linux machine ? 
I have read that there is a reference to page table in some register?

Comment: Not the page table per se, but you can look at /proc/N/maps to see the memory map per process.

Comment: Also I think newer kernels have another entry somewhere in /proc that allows you to essentially dump the entire page table hierarchy.

Comment: I think my previous post on similar topic would be useful,

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22595819/2724703

Comment: Read this for more details on exactly what a "page" means - and doesn't mean - for Linux memory management: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1

Answer (score 0):

On x86, there exists the cr3 register which points to the page tables for your process. You can't access this outside of ring-0, though, so you have to rely on something like /proc/self/pagemap to find out about the page tables.

If you just want to see what's mapped where in your process, then look at /proc/self/maps.
If you really want to know about the underlying physical frames, look at /proc/self/pagemap.

Here's some more detailed information about the pagemap file:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt